# Visual Studio 2010 setup wizard repair or remove feature

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I have a Setup wizard project created for my Forms Application.
So whenever i modify the version number and rebuild my setup wizard project and try to install, it gives me this Popup - "Another version of this product is already installed, installation cannot continue. Go to Control Panel Add/Remove programs"
Instead of this above behaviour i want to have a "Remove / Repair" feature for my Setup.
How can i do this.
I have set DetectNewerInstalledVersion= true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a major upgrade (which is the only update method supported by VS setup projects) this still applies:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/

with the addition that now you must update files versions of files that need replacing.

You get Repair/Remove by running the same MSI file again, with the same version etc, but I suspect that's not what you want - it repairs the existing product and doesn't use the new MSI you built.